# Vertical TabbarController (or TabBar)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Is there any custom `TabBarController` or some other way to get the `UITabbar` on landscape mode as vertical (not horizontal).

When the app starts, the `TabBars` will be at bottom (horizontal) but when user will rotate screen, the `tabBarController` will switch to vertical mode on left side.

I have been thinking of using native `UITabBar` and on rotation of device, to use `CoreAnimation` to rotate it but I am not sure if this approach is good or not.

Comment: In what device are you trying to run this?

Comment: I suppose it was clearly understandable by tags..ios (iphone, ipad)

Answer (score 2):

I translated  futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController into Swift 5.

My repo is https://github.com/coyingcat/VerticalTabBar

---

Apple's doc **Implementing a Container View Controller** is great also

Adding a Child View Controller to Your Content is not hard, so is Removing a Child View Controller

Comment: How do we support both vertical and horizontal based on orientation. please suggest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894031/swift-how-to-detect-orientation-changes

Comment: thank you. So with this we should change/use custom tabbar right?. Or something we could do with same implementation what you have provided. Please let me know

Comment: Yes,. just try , Then It looks like duck, it is duck

Answer (score 1):

@Joy

FSVerticalTabBarController - https://github.com/futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController is a very good custom vertical tab bar controller.

Comment: How to use FSVerticalTabBarController in swift 4.2