# Swift - How to detect orientation changes

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add two images to single image view (i.e for landscape one image and for portrait another image)but i don't know how to detect orientation changes using swift languages.

I tried this answer but it takes only one image

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

I am new to iOS development,any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please edit your question and format your code? You can do that with cmd+k when you have your code selected.

Comment: check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666269/ios8-swift-how-to-detect-orientation-change

Comment: Does it print landscape/portrait correctly?

Comment: yes it prints correctly @simpleBob

Comment: You should use interface orientation instead of device orientation => https://stackoverflow.com/a/60577486/8780127

Comment: Check this one if you want to detect changes right when the app launches.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452650/in-swift-how-to-get-the-device-orientation-correctly-right-after-its-launched/49058588#49058588

Answer (score 169, accepted):

```
let const = "Background" //image name
let const2 = "GreyBackground" // image name
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: const)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
            print("Landscape")
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: const2)
        } else {
            print("Portrait")
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: const)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you it works for imageView,what if i want to add background image to viewController??

Comment: Put a imageView on background. Give constraint to the imageView for top,bottom,leading,trailing to ViewController main view to cover all the background.

Comment: Don't forget to call super.viewWillTransitionToSize within your override method

Comment: Do you know why I can't override `viewWillTransition` when subclassing `UIView`?

Comment: There is another orientation type: `.isFlat`. If you only want to catch `portrait` I suggest you change the else clause to `else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait`. Note: `.isFlat` can happen in both, portrait and landscape, and with just else {} it will default there always (even if it's flat lanscape).

Comment: To handle all the possible cases you should use interface orientation instead => https://stackoverflow.com/a/60577486/8780127

Comment: for some reason, this did not detect portrait for me when the simulator's iPhone was upside down.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between interface orientation and device orientation

Answer (score 107):

Using **NotificationCenter** and [UIDevice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620041-begingeneratingdeviceorientation)'s `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications`

**Swift 4.2+**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.rotated), name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}

deinit {
   NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)         
}

func rotated() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
}

deinit {
     NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

func rotated() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you bother with using the notification center, when you can use the `viewWillTransitionToSize` delegate, and refrain from adding and removing the observers?

Comment: Definitely - my approach needs some additional code. But it really "detects orientation changes".

Comment: @Michael Because `viewWillTransition:` anticipates the change will happen while using `UIDeviceOrientationDidChange` is called once the change is complete.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I still believe that the described behaviour can be achieved without using the potentially dangerous NSNotificationCenter. Please review the following answer, and let me know your thoughts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26944087/1306884

Comment: What's interesting in this answer is that this will give the current orientation even when the view controller's `shouldAutorotate` is set to `false`. This is handy for screens like the Camera app's main screen--the orientation is locked but the buttons can rotate.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for handling orientation changes as there's no override method to determine what happens after the view rotates. For instance, I have an animation that I need to play before the view rotates and pause after it rotates to keep the frame from getting screwy if its paused when the view rotates.

Comment: This method is also useful when you need to tell to some nested objects, not connected directly to the view controller (like a table in table cells or collection view in a table cell), that they should be updated. These objects don't have the viewWillTransitionToSize method themselves. /!\ But I noticed some really dangerous behaviour—this notification triggers by the gyroscope/accelerator even when you change the front angle of the device without rotation, what can lead to unrequested table refresh for example. Be careful to use it!

Comment: The answer that @Michael linked should be the accepted answer.

Comment: As of iOS 9 you don't even need to explicitly call deinit.  You can read more about it here: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/unregistering-nsnotificationcenter-observers-in-ios-9/

Comment: Using viewWillTransition(to) function is not called on iPad - as its only called if a size class changes - if you need to detect orientation on an iPad, this is the correct answer. Otherwise you need to return a custom size class for the view in question.

Comment: Since Swift 4.2 the notification name has been updated from `NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange` to `UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification`

Comment: Works great for ARKit rotation check as well!

Comment: Actually you can return the UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue for more detail:
0:unknown, 1:portrait, 2:portraitUpsideDown, 3:landscapeLeft, 4:landscapeRight, 5:faceUp, 6:faceDown
In addition to the answer: it can be checked for the booleans: isFlat, isLandscape, isPortrait, isValidInterfaceOrientation
[Apple's Docu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideviceorientation)

Answer (score 101):

## ⚠️Device Orientation != Interface Orientation⚠️

#### Swift 5.* iOS16 and below

You should really make a difference between:

- Device Orientation => Indicates the orientation of the physical device
- Interface Orientation => Indicates the orientation of the interface displayed on the screen

There are many scenarios where those 2 values are mismatching such as:

- When you lock your screen orientation
- When you have your device flat

In most cases you would want to use the interface orientation and you can get it via the window:

```
private var windowInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation? {
    return UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation
}
```

In case you also want to support < iOS 13 (such as iOS 12) you would do the following:

```
private var windowInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation? {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        return UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation
    } else {
        return UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation
    }
}
```

Now you need to define where to react to the window interface orientation change. There are multiple ways to do that but the optimal solution is to do it within
 `willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection`.

This inherited UIViewController method which can be overridden will be trigger every time the interface orientation will be change. Consequently you can do all your modifications in the latter.

Here is a **solution** example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.willTransition(to: newCollection, with: coordinator)
        
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
            guard let windowInterfaceOrientation = self.windowInterfaceOrientation else { return }
            
            if windowInterfaceOrientation.isLandscape {
                // activate landscape changes
            } else {
                // activate portrait changes
            }
        })
    }
    
    private var windowInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation? {
        return UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation
    }
}
```

By implementing this method you'll then be able to react to any change of orientation to your interface. But keep in mind that it won't be triggered at the opening of the app so you will also have to manually update your interface in `viewWillAppear()`.

I've created a sample project which underlines the difference between device orientation and interface orientation. Additionally it will help you to understand the different behavior depending on which lifecycle step you decide to update your UI.

Feel free to clone and run the following repository:
https://github.com/wjosset/ReactToOrientation

Comment: I find this answer the best and most informative. But testing on iPadOS13.5 the use of suggested `func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)` did not work. I've made it work using `func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)`.

Comment: Hello @WilfriedJosset, I tried this solution but it does not work when the Phone orientation is Locked. Can you please help me?

Comment: @PersianBlue hey! if the user lock the phone orientation, well it should not rotate/animate/trigger anything then, sounds quite logical to me, but I probably don't understand the entire scope of your question. What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: @WilfriedJosset So if you check the default phone camera the icon like flash, camera switch etc rotates even when the phone rotation is locked. I was trying to implement a similar feature but I guess that would not be possible as maybe because apple has own internal way of detecting the rotation

Comment: @PersianBlue For this specific use case you might want to try to observe the DEVICE orientation (not interface) => https://stackoverflow.com/a/40263064/8780127

Comment: @WilfriedJosset I tried that already. The orientationDidChangeNotification does not get notified when the Phone orientation is locked

Comment: @PersianBlue well you could try to hack it by using CoreMotion => https://medium.com/@maximbilan/how-to-use-core-motion-in-ios-using-swift-1287f7422473
Might be refused by Apple though

Comment: @WilfriedJosset Ah !! thanks a lot that sounds like a good idea

Comment: You saved my life!
For some reason I was changing device orientation, but when I tried to get the current orientation, orientation was the same as it was before I made the rotation.

Comment: @WilfriedJosset love you man. save lot's of time of me

Comment: windows on UIApplication is deprecated and I'm using this recently - it should work as long as your are not using several scenes (think iPad) `public extension UIApplication { static var firstSceneWindows: [UIWindow] { let windows: [UIWindow] if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene { windows = windowScene.windows } else { windows = .init() } return windows } }` and then you can replace `UIApplication.shared.windows` with `UIApplication.firstSceneWindows`.

Answer (score 81):

**Swift 3** 
Above code updated:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know why I can't override viewWillTransition when subclassing UIView?

Comment: This will crash if you attempt to reference any of the views in the controller.

Comment: @JamesJordanTaylor could you please explain why it will crash?

Comment: It was 6 months ago when I commented, but I think the reason Xcode gave when I tried it was a nil pointer exception because the view itself had not yet been instantiated, just the viewController.  I could be misremembering though.

Comment: @Xcoder this is a function on UIViewController not UIView - that's why you can't override it.

Comment: this works on swift 3-5 but don't forget to call 'super' before anything else

Comment: Note that there is a difference between interface orientation and device orientation

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 4+:**
I was using this for soft keyboard design, and for some reason the `UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape` method kept telling me it was `Portrait`, so here's what I used instead:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    if(size.width > self.view.frame.size.width){
        //Landscape
    }
    else{
        //Portrait
    }
}
```

Comment: well, I do have a similar problem in my iMessage app. Isn't it really weird? And, even your solution works the opposite!! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Do not use UIScreen.main.bounds, because it might give you the screen bounds prior to the transition (mind the 'Will' in the method), especially on multiple fast rotations. You should use the 'size' parameter...

Comment: @dan-bodnar Do you mean the nativeBounds parameter?

Comment: @asetniop, no. The `size` parameter that is injected in viewWillTransitionToSize:withCoordinator: method you written above. This will reflect the exact size that your view will have after the transition.

Comment: This isn't a good solution if you are using child view controllers, the size might of the container might be square always, regardless of orientation.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a modern Combine solution:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

class MyClass: UIViewController {

     private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
    
         NotificationCenter
             .default
             .publisher(for: UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)
             .sink { [weak self] _ in
            
                 let orientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
                 print("Landscape: \(orientation.isLandscape)")
         }
         .store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If your are using Swift version >= 3.0 there are some code updates you have to apply as others have already said. Just don't forget to call super:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

   super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

   // YOUR CODE OR FUNCTIONS CALL HERE

}
```

If you are thinking to use a StackView for your images be aware you can do something like the following:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

   super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

   if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {

      stackView.axis = .horizontal

   } else {

      stackView.axis = .vertical

   } // else

}
```

If your are using Interface Builder don't forget to select the custom class for this UIStackView object, in the Identity Inspector section at the right panel. Then just create (also through Interface Builder) the IBOutlet reference to the custom UIStackView instance:

```
@IBOutlet weak var stackView: MyStackView!
```

Take the idea and adapt it to your needs. Hope this can help you!

Comment: Good point about calling super.  It is really sloppy coding to not call the super method in an overridden function and it can produce unpredictable behavior in apps.  And potentially bugs that are really hard to track down!

Comment: Do you know why I can't override viewWillTransition when subclassing UIView?

Comment: @Xcoder The reason (usually) of an object not applying an override lies in the runtime instance wasn't created with the custom class but with the default instead. If you are using Interface Builder be sure of selecting the custom class for this UIStackView object, in the Identity Inspector section at the right panel.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4.2, RxSwift**

If we need to reload collectionView.

```
NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(UIDevice.orientationDidChangeNotification)
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .map { _ in }            
    .bind(to: collectionView.rx.reloadData)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

**Swift 4, RxSwift**

If we need to reload collectionView.

```
NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange)
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
    .map { _ in }            
    .bind(to: collectionView.rx.reloadData)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe the correct answer is actually a combination of both approaches: `viewWIllTransition(toSize:)` and `NotificationCenter`'s `UIDeviceOrientationDidChange`.

`viewWillTransition(toSize:)` notifies you **before** the transition.

`NotificationCenter` `UIDeviceOrientationDidChange` notifies you **after**.

You have to be very careful. For example, in `UISplitViewController` when the device rotates into certain orientations, the `DetailViewController` gets popped off the `UISplitViewController`'s `viewcontrollers` array, and pushed onto the master's `UINavigationController`. If you go searching for the detail view controller before the rotation has finished, it may not exist and crash.

Comment: Overriding `willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection` might also be a safe gamble.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4**

I've had some minor issues when updating the ViewControllers view using `UIDevice.current.orientation`, such as updating constraints of tableview cells during rotation or animation of subviews.

Instead of the above methods I am currently comparing the transition size to the view controllers view size. This seems like the proper way to go since one has access to both at this point in code:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    print("Will Transition to size \(size) from super view size \(self.view.frame.size)")

    if (size.width > self.view.frame.size.width) {
        print("Landscape")
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
    }

    if (size.width != self.view.frame.size.width) {
        // Reload TableView to update cell's constraints.
    // Ensuring no dequeued cells have old constraints.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


}
```

Output on a iPhone 6:

```
Will Transition to size (667.0, 375.0) from super view size (375.0, 667.0) 
Will Transition to size (375.0, 667.0) from super view size (667.0, 375.0)
```

Comment: Should I have to turn on orientation support from project level?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `viewWillTransition(to:with:)` and tap into `animate(alongsideTransition:completion:)` to get the interface orientation AFTER the transition is complete. You just have to define and implement a protocol similar to this in order to tap into the event. **Note that this code was used for a SpriteKit game and your specific implementation may differ.**

```
protocol CanReceiveTransitionEvents {
    func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize)
    func interfaceOrientationChanged(to orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation)
}
```

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

        guard
            let skView = self.view as? SKView,
            let canReceiveRotationEvents = skView.scene as? CanReceiveTransitionEvents else { return }

        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: nil) { _ in
            if let interfaceOrientation = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation {
                canReceiveRotationEvents.interfaceOrientationChanged(to: interfaceOrientation)
            }
        }

        canReceiveRotationEvents.viewWillTransition(to: size)
    }
```

You can set *breakpoints* in these functions and observe that `interfaceOrientationChanged(to orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation)` is always called after `viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize)` with the updated orientation.

Answer (score 4):

All previous contributes are fine, but a little note:

a) if orientation is set in plist, only portrait or example, You will be **not** notified via viewWillTransition

b) if we anyway need to know if user has rotated device, (for example a game or similar..) we can only use:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
```

tested on Xcode8, iOS11

Answer (score 2):

To get the correct orientation on **app start** you have to check it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`. Other methods described here won't work.

Here's an example how to do it:

```
var mFirstStart = true

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    if (mFirstStart) {
        mFirstStart = false
        detectOrientation()
    }
}

func detectOrientation() {
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        print("Landscape")
        // do your stuff here for landscape
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
        // do your stuff here for portrait
    }
}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    detectOrientation()
}
```

This will work always, on **app first start**, and if rotating **while the app is running**.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to detect device orientations is with the function traitCollectionDidChange(_:). The system calls this method when the iOS interface environment changes.

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?)
{
    super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
    //...
}
```

Furthermore, you can use function willTransition(to:with:) ( which is called before traitCollectionDidChange(_:) ), to get information just before the orientation is applied.

```
 override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{
    super.willTransition(to: newCollection, with: coordinator)
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My app is running on iOS 15 and I have checked only on iPhone/iPad so I can't say about all use cases however I am using the following environment variable:

`@Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) private var verticalSizeClass`

Then checking its value using the following:
`verticalSizeClass == .compact` is horizontal
`verticalSizeClass == .regular` is vertical

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/verticalsizeclass