# swift detect orientation change

Tags: swift, orientation

I'm using Swift 2 in Legancy language version.
The problem is that i can't detect orientation changes with this code :

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator);

    if size.height<size.width {
        print("Landscape");
    } else {
        print("Portrait");
    }
}
```

that works until a few weeks ago.
how can i fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect orientation change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25666269/how-to-detect-orientation-change)

Comment: no because in my AppDelegate.sfift i don't have "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"

Comment: So, instead of your if statement evaluating size, could you not do `if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue`

Comment: i have already tried but notthing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift - How to detect orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894031/swift-how-to-detect-orientation-changes)