# Adjust the position of layer with transparent hole when view change from portrait to landscape

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, mask, layer

I am using this code to create a layer with a transparent hole

```
let radius = min(self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)
    print(radius)
    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height), cornerRadius: 0)
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.size.height/2 - radius/2 , width: radius, height: radius), cornerRadius: radius/2)
    path.append(circlePath)

    path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true

    fillLayer.path = path.cgPath
    fillLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    fillLayer.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    fillLayer.opacity = 0.5
    view.layer.addSublayer(fillLayer)
```

it works fine if the initial view is portrait or landscape as show in the image

[image]

However if the view changes from portrait to landscape or landscape to portrait

The layer is not properly oriented as shown

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'll need to update the frame of your path whenever the user rotates their device. You're looking for something like the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38894031/swift-how-to-detect-orientation-changes).

If you need to animate along with the transition, try something like this:

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { context in            
        // update frames here
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this but i dont like because the transition of layer with hole isnot smooth

Comment: @Ahmed I updated my answer with an animation. Does that help?