# Support portrait and landscape orientation for UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift5, landscape-portrait

I am new to IOS development and I have a basic UITableView with rows to display data.
The problem I am facing is that UITableView is not reacting to the landscape orientation.

I have the following code which does not work:

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I find it quite tricky to find solution on the internet.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry but remove this code of line. And Check in project that if project supports portrait and landscape mode.

Comment: You have a look to that post, it might clarify few things => https://stackoverflow.com/a/60577486/8780127

Comment: To explain in detail - there shouldn't be a need to call `reloadData` on a change in orientation. All a change in orientation eans is a change in *layout* (potentially), not *data*. From what your question indicates, your table is either (a) sideways or (b) not displaying it's **unchanged** data properly on an orientation change.

Comment: @Kudos where do I check the orientation settings in project? I could not find any.

Comment: @dfd what do you mean sideways? That the tableview is not rotating?

Do you know how I can fix this? I cannot use constraints on the UITableView and the cells